# Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Assigning retained object to unsafe_unretained variable; object will be released after assignment

Tags: objective-c, object, automatic-ref-counting, alloc

I'm getting this warning

> "Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Assigning retained object to unsafe_unretained variable; object will be released after assignment"

Here is the code

.h

```
@interface myObject : NSObject
{
}

@property (assign) id progressEnergy;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation myObject

@synthesize progressEnergy;

-(id)init
{
    if ( ( self = [super init] ) )
    {
        progressEnergy = [[progress alloc] init]; //warning appear on this line
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

I have already tried

```
@property (assign) progress* progressEnergy;
```

but no luck

Can you please help me figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Change

```
@property (assign) progress* progressEnergy;
```

to

```
@property (strong) progress* progressEnergy;
```

so your `myObject` retains the `progress` object.

Answer (score 10):

Well it's warning you that you're assigning a value that's about to get released at the end of the enclosing scope, which happens to be the next line. So this is what your `init` will look like after ARC adds in its magic:

```
-(id)init
{
    if ( ( self = [super init] ) )
    {
        progressEnergy = [[progress alloc] init];
        [progressEnergy release]; ///< Release progressEnergy since we've hit the end of the scope we created it in
    }

    return self;
}
```

So your `progressEnergy` is now extremely likely (although not necessarily) to be a dangling pointer.

Change the definition of the property from `assign` to `strong`:

```
@property (strong) progress* progressEnergy;
```

In that case, your `init` method will look like:

```
-(id)init
{
    if ( ( self = [super init] ) )
    {
        progressEnergy = [[progress alloc] init];
        [progressEnergy retain]; ///< Since it's a strong property
        [progressEnergy release]; ///< Release progressEnergy since we've hit the end of the scope we created it in
    }

    return self;
}
```

In actual fact, it calls `objc_storeStrong` instead of calling `retain` like I've shown, but essentially it boils down to a `retain` in this case.